# Ethers contract on method "No mathing event" error

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, ethers.js

I just started learning `ethers`, here is my code:

```
(async () => {
  const connection = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/key"
  );

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    "0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b",
    abi,
    connection
  );

  contract.on("atomicMatch_", (...args) => {
    console.log(args);
  });
})();
```

so the contract is `opensea` main contract - [link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b)
I would like to listen to sales transactions/events. As I see in the contract name of that event is probably `Atomic Match_` or `atomicMatch_` in ABI.
For ABI I just copy pasted whole contract to https://remix.ethereum.org/ website and copied abi code. The problem is I am getting this error now:

`Error: no matching event (argument="name", value="atomicMatch_", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)`

What is wrong here? I tried both names of event but I get the same error over and over...

@edit here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ethers-playground-forked-ib3o2?file=/src/App.js) for it,
what is weird when I change event name to `OrdersMatched` for example it works totally fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethers `contract.on()` ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-on)) is invoked when an event with the specified name is emitted.

Your snippet is passing a function name (`atomicMatch_`), not an event name.

The `atomicMatch_` function effectively emits the event named `OrdersMatched`. That's why changing the handler to `contract.on('OrdersMatched')` fixes the issue.

---

Also, the sandbox is using a built-in provider under the `getDefaultProvider()`, which is communicating with the app over WSS. Your snippet is using a HTTPS provider that is by design unable to listen to events. You'll need to use a WSS provider as well (they are supported by Infura).

Comment: Hmm that is interesting because when I put `wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/key` link there I do not get any response, when I put `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/key` it works fine so it looks like it works the other way you described

Comment: @Sowam That is interesting. I'm not that familiar with the Ethers.js library, maybe they're actively polling the requests over HTTPS (asking each X seconds for an update), and the WSS malfunction might be related to something else... Generally, WSS keeps an open connection allowing for constant flow of messages both ways - while during HTTPS connection your app acts as a client sending separate requests to the server, but a server can't send a message to a client without the client's prior request... Maybe someone more skilled in Ethers.js and/or Infura will be able to resolve it better.

Comment: I fixed that by changing `ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider` to `thers.providers.WebSocketProvider`, works fine now, thanks